# Animating into a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I know how to animate a view to go straight or sideways using the xml and animators.

```
        AnimatorSet translate = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(),R.animator.anim_translate);
        translate.setTarget(button);           
        translate.start();
```

anim_translate:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="sequentially" >

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="300"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="translationX"
    android:valueTo="400" /></set>
```

But how can I make a view animate into another view - a layout?